# value changed to undefined when coming outside the loop

Tags: node.js, express

The value of rows[i] is perfectly printing inside the loop, but when we print it outside it becomes undefined.I don't want to use  set timeout function in my program.

```
 function listshops(callback)
        {   
         client.connection.query('select * from shop',function(err,rows){
           if(rows.length>0)
           { 
             for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
             {   
               (function(i){
               var shopIdFetched = rows[i].shopId;
               client.connection.query('select * from image where shopId=?',shopIdFetched,function(err,data){
                 if(data.length > 0){
                  var result = rows[i].image = JSON.stringify(data);   
                    }
                  });
               })(i);
              }
              console.log(rows[i]);

             }

          });
        }
```

output:[image: output]

Comment: what are the errors you are getting.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are getting undefined cause your `i` in `rows[i]` is out of index. But solving that wont solve your problem as you are performing multiple asynchronous task within a for loop. Your rows object will not be populated by the time you print it.

**Solution:** You need to use async or promises for performing the task.

```
// Include the async package
var async = require("async");
client.connection.query('select * from shop',function(err,rows){
if(rows.length>0)
   {
    // 1st para in async.each() is the array of items
    async.each(rows,
      // 2nd param is the function that each item is passed to
      function(item, callback){
        // Call an asynchronous function,
        var shopIdFetched = item.shopId;
        client.connection.query('select * from image where shopId=?',shopIdFetched,function(err,data){
             if(data.length > 0){         
              item.image = JSON.stringify(data);   
              }
              callback();//required
             });


      },

      // 3rd param is the function to call when everything's done
      function(err){

        if(err){
          console.log('Error:' + err);
        }
        console.log(rows);// your result
      }
    );
   }           
});
```

Comment: i have one more doubt that is:  i want to execute one more query inside for each loop 
 client.connection.query('select * from category where shopId=?',shopIdFetched,function(err,data2){
     if(data2.length > 0){          
        var result = rows[i].category = data2;   
         arr.push(rows[i]);        
         }

Comment: You need to perform these two operations in series one after the other, as it will make handling exceptions better, also callback() can only be called once. There are two ways, one is you call the next function (category) inside image fetching callback function and then call callback() inside it. Or, you can use [async.series](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) and call both queries one after the other.

Comment: i tried this with async.series but it is returning an error :"undefined is not a function", my code is :http://i.stack.imgur.com/qRUWA.png

Comment: my expected output is : http://i.stack.imgur.com/mI6NV.png                                           please help me to solve this problem..

Comment: You are passing item in wrong way, create a local variable and then pass it in series. Do this way, [Gist Code](https://gist.github.com/nivesh2/0c36b0c5e43702433f4a1bf430cfac53) BTW there are two ways, one is you define item properties within respective callbacks or set them at the last callback function, do as you may prefer.

Comment: is there is any problem if i use async.parrallel?    i got the same result by using async.parallel.

Comment: in parallel one can not handle the error properly, cause if both of your queries throw error simultaneously then which error should be thrown ahead using callback(err). So, better option is to sequentially handle it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114648/discussion-between-nivesh-and-midhun-k).

Answer (score 0):

When you exit the loop, the value of `i` is equal to the array's length.

Let's say the length is 10, so indexes run from 0 to 9.
So in fact, after the loop, `rows[i]` is `rows[10]`, which is indeed undefined.